# How to update objects in Spring Jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have 2 tables: team and player. Entity Player has field `Team team` with joincolumn `team_id`.
I have service method, that changes team_id of table field on another one:

```java
private List<Player> setPlayerToList(Team team, Player player) {
        List<Player> players = team.getPlayers();
        players.add(player);
        return players;
    }
 @Transactional
    public Player fromTo2(String to, String playerName) {
        Player player = playerRepo.findByName(playerName);
        Team teamTo = teamRepo.findByName(to);
        List<Player> players = setPlayerToList(teamTo, player);
        teamTo.setPlayers(players);
        teamRepo.saveAndFlush(teamTo);
        return playerRepo.saveAndFlush(player);
    }
```

and controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/do")
    public ResponseEntity<?> transferPlayer(
            @RequestParam(name = "to") String to,
            @RequestParam(name = "player") String player
    ) {
        transferService.fromTo2(to, player);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
```

going `/do?to=1&player=3` for example - nothing changes.

What is wrong?. Additionally, I cant debug - placing breakpoint on `findByName` lines or return lines - program even not stops on that breakpoint and debugger is empty.

Entities

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;

    private int price;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private int budget;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Player> players;
}
```

I have no exceptions in console. Using h2database

Comment: can you add your Team an Player classes please ? and what is your console error message ?

Comment: yes sure, updated

Comment: You must set the Player on the Team not the Team  on the player, actually you are persisting the Team not the Player

replace this line 

 `player.setTeam(teamTo);`

By this

 `teamTo.setPlayer(player);`

Answer (score 0):

You must set the Player on the Team not the Team  on the player, actually you are persisting the Team not the Player

replace this line

```
player.setTeam(teamTo);
```

By this

```
teamTo.setPlayer(player);
```